Getting jsdom error in fabric while running it from library
fabric.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: jsdom.JSDOM is not a constructor
at node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js (fabric.js:25:23)
I am getting this in the browser console and which will result breaking of the canvas which is supposed to be loaded inside the application
I was expecting it to work without error even after installing the jsdom version 19
which is the same version which is been used inside the fabric js

Please share a [mcve] of your code. Include a package.json with relevant libraries and versions. Thanks.
